# PostgreSQL: How to clear a table with some columns in Toast table?

Tags: postgresql

When I use this command to clear a table (name is v_xml_cdr):

```
DELETE FROM v_xml_cdr;
```

then check table size with command \d+ ,but size of table v_xml_cdr is almost same as before.

I searched in stackoverflow and learned it's because of the Toast table, some columns such as Text type use Extended storage, PostgreSQL treats them like a blob and use a toast table to store the actual data.

```
\d+ v_xml_cdr

                                         Table "public.v_xml_cdr”
         Column         |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 uuid                   | uuid                        | not null  | plain    |              | 
 domain_uuid            | uuid                        |           | plain    |              | 
 extension_uuid         | uuid                        |           | plain    |              | 
 domain_name            | text                        |           | extended |              | 
 accountcode            | text                        |           | extended |              | 
 direction              | text                        |           | extended |              | 
...
```

Some people say that "vacuum full" command can shrink the table size after this problem happened.

But I want to know if there's a good way to avoid this problem when clearing a table, other than using "vacuum full" command.

Comment: `truncate` will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY

> In PostgreSQL, an UPDATE or DELETE of a row does not immediately
>   remove the old version of the row. This approach is necessary to gain
>   the benefits of multiversion concurrency control (MVCC, see Chapter
>   13): the row version must not be deleted while it is still potentially
>   visible to other transactions. But eventually, an outdated or deleted
>   row version is no longer of interest to any transaction. The space it
>   occupies must then be reclaimed for reuse by new rows, to avoid
>   unbounded growth of disk space requirements. This is done by running
>   VACUUM.
>
> The standard form of VACUUM removes dead row versions in tables and
>   indexes and marks the space available for future reuse. However, it
>   will not return the space to the operating system, except in the
>   special case where one or more pages at the end of a table become
>   entirely free and an exclusive table lock can be easily obtained. In
>   contrast, **VACUUM FULL actively compacts tables by writing a complete
>   new version of the table file with no dead space**. This minimizes the
>   size of the table, but can take a long time. It also requires extra
>   disk space for the new copy of the table, until the operation
>   completes.

and further:

> If you have a table whose entire contents are deleted on a periodic
>   basis, consider doing it with TRUNCATE rather than using DELETE
>   followed by VACUUM. **TRUNCATE removes the entire content of the table
>   immediately, without requiring a subsequent VACUUM or VACUUM FULL** to
>   reclaim the now-unused disk space. The disadvantage is that strict MVCC semantics are violated.

emphasis mine

Comment: Thanks Vao Tsun for the right answer!  Command `TRUNCATE TABLE v_xml_cdr;` does the work. And the most interesting thing is, it also clear the old contents which had been deleted by `DELETE FROM v_xml_cdr;` before. Check by `\d+` command again, now the size of this table is 128kB only, wonderful~